# Combine two lists in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

My code is as follows:

```
for row in lineReader:
        i=i+1
        if i<3:
          tweet = row[0] 
          label = row[1]

          train = [tweet, label]
          print train
```

Output:
['tweet0', 'label0']
['tweet1', 'label1']

Expected Output:

[('tweet0', 'label0'), ('tweet1', 'label1')]

Any suggestions on how to get the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I need to retain the tuples inside the list and not just concatenate the lists.

Comment: @Ashwin Maybe you should edit your question and be more specific about what it is you are looking to do? Also, you need to show your own coding attempt at this and explain what is currently not working in your current approach.

Comment: @Ashwin: what makes you think concatenating will do anything to the tuples? `lst1, lst2 = [('text0', 'label0')], [('text1', 'label1')]; lst1 + lst2` produces your expected output.

Comment: Yes, I tried this but i have only one variable: train = [('text0', 'label0')], [('text1', 'label1')]

Comment: If you want a list of these tuples, then define a variable `trains` before the for loop and change the last but one line to:  `trains.append([tweet, label])`. Then, `trains` will have the list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

`list1 + list2` would do the trick